# Add a web reference programmatically in .NET compact framework

Tags: web-services, compact-framework, windows-ce, web-reference

I'm using a development environment which is based on .NET compact framework for Windows CE operating system. The development environment is pretty closed, but the scripting interface is like a classic code view of a Windows forms application in Visual Studio.
I need to add a reference to a web service in order to consume some methods, but there is no visual support.
How do I add a reference / create my proxy object programmatically in the code?
Which assembly/namespace should I use?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2008 (or higher probably) if you right click the References folder for your project in the Solution Explorer pane, there is an option for "Add Web Reference". I'd do that and then copy the code generated to whatever IDE you're using (since it sounds like it's not VS). You also might be able to use [WSDL.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(v=vs.71).aspx)